# Como deixar uma estrutura modificada com efeito :active

Tags: css, css-hover

Gente, fiz o seguinte código e estou em dúvida com as pseudo-classes, no caso eu criei botões mas a alteração do efeito :active só acontece enquanto mantenho cursor pressionado, há alguma maneira de manter aquela alteração até que seja selecionado outro botão?

Abaixo está o código + css.

```css
.box {
 width: 500px;
 border: 10px solid whitesmoke;
 padding: 25px;
 display: block ruby;
}

a.dados {
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/MSCwHBz/do-utilizador.png);
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-size: 40px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #f0eaea;
 padding: 5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 border: 2px solid #8080802e;
}

a.bio {
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/Y0BCMpW/livro.png);
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-size: 34px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #f0eaea;
 padding: 5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 border: 2px solid #8080802e;
 margin: 2.5px;
}

a.rel {
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/LPgTZQJ/protecao.png);
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-size: 34px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #f0eaea;
 padding: 5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 border: 2px solid #8080802e;
 margin: 2.5px;
}

a.inv {
 background: url(https://i.ibb.co/grLSV8N/caixa.png);
 width: 40px;
 height: 40px;
 background-size: 34px;
 display: block;
 background-color: #f0eaea;
 padding: 5px;
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 border: 2px solid #8080802e;
 margin: 2.5px;
}

#dados {
 background: green;
 width: 496px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 52px;
 margin-left: -7px;
 border: 2px solid #dcd7d7;
}

#bio {
 background: #bf0606;
 width: 496px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
 margin-left: -63px;
 border: 2px solid #dcd7d7;
 display: none;
}

#rel {
 background: #0f42dd;
 width: 496px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
 margin-left: -122px;
 border: 2px solid #dcd7d7;
 display: none;
}

#inv {
 background: #b55029;
 width: 496px;
 height: 200px;
 position: absolute;
 margin-top: 55px;
 margin-left: -181px;
 border: 2px solid #dcd7d7;
 display: none;
}

a.dados:active {
 background-color: #978f8f;
}

a.bio:active {
 background-color: #978f8f;
}

a.rel:active {
 background-color: #978f8f;
}

a.inv:active {
 background-color: #978f8f;
}

a.inv:active #inv {
 display: block; !important
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
<a class="dados"><div id="dados"></div></a>
<a class="bio"><div id="bio"></div></a>
<a class="rel"><div id="rel"></div></a>
<a class="inv"><div id="inv"></div></a>
<div class="cred"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Pretende concretamente o quê? alterar a cor quando passar o cursor por cima do objeto? para isso utilize o :hover. Caso pretenda clicar e aparecer outra cor, o melhor é usar javascript com o evento onclick do html

Comment: Não, a cor foi apenas um teste, eu queria deixar a #div visível enquanto não mudam a opção.

Comment: Para deixar uma div visivel com CSS usa-se display: block. Para esconder será display: none. Ao pretender fazer isso enquanto não muda de opção pode fazer através de javascript. Na tag de html adiciona onclick="função", e no javascript chama essa função e troca o tipo de display da tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uma forma de fazer isso é controlando via JavaScript.

Para isso você pode adicionar um evento de click nos links *(tag `<a ...>`)*, quando esse evento for acionado adicionar uma classe no link que foi clicado e remover essa classe dos outros links.
Veja o exemplo abaixo, nele tento explicar o código com os comentários.

```js
/// ; Busca o elemento com a classe `box`
var box = document.querySelector('.box'),
/// ; Busca os elementos quem tem a tag `A` que estão dentro do elemento `box`
    meusLinks = box.querySelectorAll('A');
    
/// ; Para cada `A` adiciona o evento de onclick
meusLinks.forEach(function( a ){ 
   a.addEventListener('click',onCliqueiNoLink);
});



/// ; Evento de onclick
function onCliqueiNoLink(){
  
  /// ; `this` dentro dessa função é a tag `A` que foi clicada.
  console.log( this , this.parentNode );

  /// ; Pega o 'pai' do link clicado, ou seja, o elemento de classe `box`
  this.parentNode
  /// ;  busca por todos os elementos de tag `A` dentro dele
      .querySelectorAll( 'A' ) 
  /// ;  remove a classe `active` desses `A`
      .forEach( function( a ){
         a.classList.remove('active');
      });
  
  /// ; adiciona classe `active` no link clicado
  this.classList.add('active');
}
```

```css
A{ display:inline-block; width: 20px; height: 20px; background: yellow; }

A.active{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
    <a class="dados"></a>
    <a class="bio"></a>
    <a class="rel"></a>
    <a class="inv"></a>
    <div class="cred"></div>
</div>
```

> #### Referencias:
>
> [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector), [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll), [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/classList), [`addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Element/addEventListener).